# Passing data between view controllers in Swift does not work

Tags: ios, swift, view, controllers

Would you please help me? The data (itemStr) is not passed even though the below code seems correct and I have already checked the similar questions on stack overflow.com:

1st view controller (BookTableViewController.swift):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if let SecondController = segue.destination as? BookViewController {
            SecondController.itemStr = "43"        
        }        
}
```

2nd view controller (BookViewController.swift):

```
var itemStr = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        itemNoLabel?.text = "BNo:" + itemStr + " GYE"       
}
```

---

When I run the program, itemStr comes as nil. I do not get "43"?

Thanks, in advance, for your kind help.
Guven

Comment: `itemStr` can't be `nil`, it's not an optional. Do you mean it is the empty string? But a breakpoint on the line in `viewDidLoad` and in `prepare` and see when each is called.

Comment: If you tried to add a breakpoint to the line of `SecondController.itemStr = "43"`, will it be reachable? Also, are you sure that `itemStr` is not been set as `""` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Dear Ahmad, thank you very much for your prompt reply. But this time, itemNoLabel shows the default label's text, not "BNo:"...? Thanks, Guven.

Comment: No. itemStr is not set as "" in the code.

Comment: Why are you initializing `itemStr`? Simply set it to *be* a String (declare it as `var itemStr:String?`). I believe (but actually only believe) that your syntax creates a "null string" upon the VC being initialized, which may be in a completely different "lifecycle" (view and/or VC) than what is happening. Whatever the case, that's the *first* thing I'd change and have never seen a segue syntax trying that. Second? Why are you using `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillAppear`? Your code implies a nav controller. Users can toggle between controllers. They actually load *and/or* appear.

Comment: I assume you are using storyboards. Is it possible that you forgot to set the second storyboard's class to `BookViewController` in the storyboard file? I've forgotten to do that before

Comment: @dfd, tried viewWillAppear but no change. There is a nav controller before the second view controller in the storyboard. Thanks.

Comment: @Gabriel, checked that the class name is selected as BookViewController on the storyboard identity inspector tab.

Comment: *"There is a nav controller before the second view controller"* ... Do you mean your segue goes from `BookTableViewController` to a **nav controller** that has a root VC of `BookViewController`? Or is your segue direct to `BookViewController`? (maybe edit your question with a screen-cap of the related controllers in your storyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into problems because you're not really presenting the `UIViewController` that you think you are. You're really presenting it's `UINavigationViewController`.

But you could still do something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if let navigationViewController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {

            guard let secondViewController = navigationViewController.topViewController as? BookViewController else { return }
            secondViewController.itemStr = "43"        
        }        
}
```